# Internet Explorer Support got Dropped

Tags: javascript, reactjs, internet-explorer

From one day to another, my react app no longer works on Internet Explorer

It works like a charm on Google Chrome,

I tried to alert the user on the Index Page of the React index.js directory, but the code breaks before even getting to index.js

Any ideas ?

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

console.log("first");  <---- this never runs 
alert(navigator.userAgent);

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

DEBUG FROM Internet Explorer

[image]

var n=window.location.href

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So Internet Explorer Armageddon is happening all over the place...

Place this right after the  tag in public/index.html to let users know to upgrade

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<script>
      window.onload = function () {
        var browserCheck = navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Trident");
        if (browserCheck !== -1) {
          alert(
            "go get google chrome foo"
          );
        }
      };
</script>
```